# Python (CherryPy) web app deployed locally, but not visible over intranet

Tags: python, cherrypy, intranet

I've created a Python web app using CherryPy, and have deployed in on my local machine.

When I try to view it from another computer in the house, nothing comes back.

However, if I create a simple html file, and deploy it with:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

It is visible over the intranet.

I'm stumped as to why my app could work locally, but not be avalable over the intranet, given that there is not a connection problem between these machines, and that I can serve other content on the same port.

I have not used a configuration file, I'm using the default CherryPy settings.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The default settings likely bind to localhost, which is not publicly available.  If you want CherryPy to run on a public interface, you'll have to direct it to do that.  From [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/66c2a3e0baef9a48) I found:

```
cherrypy.config.update(
    {'server.socket_host': '10.149.4.240' } ) # Pub IP
cherrypy.quickstart()
```

or

```
cherrypy.config.update(
    {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'} )      
cherrypy.quickstart()
```

To bind to all interfaces.

Comment: You should be fine with 0.0.0.0.  That is basically your local computer, publicly accessible (while the default 127.0.0.1 is your local computer, not publicly accessible).

Comment: To clarify this answer, one way to configure the socket host is to call `cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})` before calling `cherrypy.quickstart()`. A config file could also be used.